# Because of this middleware, I am getting error .without this everything works smoothly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
function checkCampgroundOwnership(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        Campground.findById(req.params.id , function(err,foundCampground){
            if(err){
                res.redirect("back");
            }else{
                //does the user own the campground
                if(foundCampground.author.id.equals(req.user._id)) {
                    next();                                                    
                    //res.render("/campgrounds/edit",{campground:foundCampground});
                }
                else{
                    res.redirect("back");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

Is there any problem with the **middleware here**? Please help..

```
router.get("/campgrounds/:id/edit",checkCampgroundOwnership, 
function(req,res){   
Campground.findById(req.params.id , function(err,foundCampground){
       if(err){
           res.redirect("/campgrounds");
              } else{
            res.render("campground/edit",{campground: foundCampground});
              }
        });
```

});

```
router.put("/campgrounds/:id",checkCampgroundOwnership, function(req,res){
Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.campground
,function(err, updatedCampground){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/campgrounds");
            console.log("It's working bad");
        }else{

            res.redirect("/campgrounds/" + req.params.id );
            console.log("It's working fine");
        }
```

}); 
});

these routes are to edit and update the blog post, I am getting error " No default engine was specified and no extension was provided."

Comment: can you show your post route ?

Comment: @ShivKumar Done